# How to remove this last divider in CSS?

Tags: css, css-selectors

Hi I want to get rid of the last divider in this menu 
http://prntscr.com/1dmia <- as you can see here at the 'Contact Us' link , after that there is divider , I want to not show it.
Ive tried this

```
#nav ul li:last:after{
content:'';
}
```

but doesnt work

here's the markup of the menu

HTML

```
<div id="nav" class="center"><!-- nav [START] -->
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#" title="Home">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" title="Artist Gallery">Artist Gallery</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" title="Make an Appointment">Make an Appointment</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" title="Location">Location</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" title="Contact Us">Contact Us</a></li>
                </ul>
</div><!-- nav [END] -->
```

The CSS

```
#nav ul li{
float:left; 
margin-top:10px;
margin-right:35px;
}

#nav ul li:after{
content:'l';
color:#d40202;
margin-left:20px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You want `:last-child`:

```
#nav ul li:last-child:after {
    content: '';
}
```

But bearing in mind that that pseudo-class is CSS3-only (unlike `:first-child` which is CSS2), you're better off giving the last `li` its own ID or class, and selecting that instead, which more browsers understand:

```
#nav ul li.last:after {
    content: '';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `last-child`?

```
#nav ul li:last-child:after
{
  content: '';
}
```

Comment: omfg, lol , Why I didnt think of that, I was using :last not :last-child ,thanks man for helping  .